# Waiting for a response from app.post in another app.post

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm developing a back-end for a mobile application using express.js for my API.

For this mobile application, the users sign-in using mobile numbers, an OTP code is sent to their mobiles, and they need to send back the OTP they received to the server for verification and validation.

When the users first attempt to sign-in, they POST their mobile number to the server, and then a bunch of processing happens, and an OTP is sent to them through an SMS gateway.

Now while this request is still ongoing, I need to wait for the users to send the OTP through a POST request to another route, verify it, and then proceed on with the appropriate steps in the first, ongoing POST request.

After some search on the net, I eventually decided to wrap the app.post method for the verifyOTP route in a function that creates and returns a new promise, and then resolve it or reject it after verification. This worked wonderfully for the first time I perform this operation after restarting the server, but that's it. It only works the first time, and then for the consecutive times that follow, none of the new promises that should be created are resolved or rejected, and the first request to the sign-in route remains waiting.

I tried a bunch of things like making the function wrapping the verifyOTP route async, and creating promises inside the route instead of wrapping it in one, but still no use. Can you help me?

For the sake of finding a solution for this problem, I've simplified the process and did a simulation of the actual situation using this code, and it simulates the problem well:

**This is to simulate the first request:**

```
app.get("/test", async function(req, res) {
    console.log("Test route\n");

    var otpCode = Math.floor(Math.random() * (9999 - 2)) + 1;
    var timestamp = Date.now();

    otp = {
        code: otpCode,
        generated: timestamp
    };

    console.log("OTP code sent: " + otpCode + "\n");
    console.log("OTP sent.\n");

    res.end();

    /*  verifyOTP().then(function() {
            console.log("Resolved OTP verification\n\n");
            res.end();
        }).catch(function() {
            console.log("Bad\n\n");
            res.end();
        });*/
});
```

**This is the verifyOTP route:**

```
var otp;

app.post("/verifyOTP", function(req, res) {
    console.log("POST request - verify OTP request\n");

    var msg;
    if ((Date.now() - otp.generated) / 1000 > 30) {
        msg = "OTP code is no longer valid.";
        res.status(403).json({
            error: msg
        });
    } else {
        var submitted = req.body.otp;
        if (submitted !== otp.code) {
            msg = "OTP code is incorrect.";
            res.status(403).json({
                error: msg
            });
        } else {
            msg = "Verified.";
            res.end();
        }
    }
    console.log(res.statusCode + " - " + res.statusMessage + "\n");
    console.log(msg + "\n");
});
```

Just to mention, this isn't the only place in my server that I need OTP verification, although the implementation of what happens after the verification varies. Therefore, I'd appreciate it if the solution could still keep the code reusable for multiple instances..

Comment: While it is *technically* possible to do things that way, it is a terrible idea which will break a lot of the time when the browser times out before the user has sent the OTP. Do what everyone else does: Respond telling the user they need the OTP code and providing a form for them to enter it into. Then continue the journey with the response to getting the code.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.. I'll try to make it reusable for the several cases I need the OTP verification for..

Comment: No use. That just created a ton of other errors with the database connection and the sending of a response..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some more research on my own, I discarded the use of Promises for this use case all together, and instead used RxJS' Observables..

It solved my problem pretty much the way I want it, although I had to do some slight modifications..

**For those who stumble upon my question looking for a solution for the same problem I faced:**

Promises can only be resolved or rejected once, and as far as I can tell, unless the Promises function *finishes* running, you can't create a new one with the same code (please correct me if I'm wrong on this one, I'd really appreciate it, this was only based on my own personal observations and guesswork), and unless you create a brand new Promise, you can't resolve it again.

In this case, we are making a Promise out of a listener (or whatever it's called in js), so unless you delete the listener, the function warapped inside the promise won't finish running (I think), and you won't get to create a new Promise.

Observables, on the other hand, can be reused as many times as you want, see [this](https://medium.com/javascript-everyday/javascript-theory-promise-vs-observable-d3087bc1239a) for a comparison between Promises and Observables, and [this](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/148/RxJS-Observables-Tutorial---Creating-&-Subscribing-to-Observables) for a nice tutorial that will help you understand Observables and how to use them. See [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rxjs) for how to install RxJS for node.

However, be warned - for some reason, once you subscribe to an observable, the variables used in the function passed to observable.subscribe() remains the same, it doesn't get updated with every new request you make to the observer route. So unless you find a way to pass the variables that change into the observer.next() function inside the observable definition, you will get the wrong results.